# Spritekit - Overlapping Text

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

How can I stop my text over lapping every time the text is updated. Each time that the text updates it will place the text on top of the previous text. Here is my code I've used to implement the HUD.

**HUD Setup**

```
-(void)createHUD {
    id wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.5];
    id run = [SKAction runBlock:^ {
    //delete after 1.5 seconds then reset it so that it doesnt overlap cuase its really annoying to watch that happen

    counter++;
    updateLabel = true;

    counterLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    counterLabel.name = @"myCounterLabel";
    //counterLabel.text = @"0";
    counterLabel.fontSize = 50;
    counterLabel.fontColor = [SKColor yellowColor];
    counterLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.0f, self.size.height / 1.3f);

    [self addChild: counterLabel];
}];
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[wait, run]]];
    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[wait, run]]]];
}
```

**Update Method**

```
    -(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if(updateLabel == true) {
    counterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
    updateLabel = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are u updating the label in the update method at all?

Comment: Also, why do you need to delete and re-initialise the label each time the counter updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

- You do not need to update the counterLabel from the update method. This is simply adding extra processing to the update loop for something which needs to be carried out only once in 1.5 seconds.
- You can update the label from within the block itself. This will make your implementation much simpler.

Have a look at the following method. It should be able to achieve what you are attempting.

```
-(void)createHUD {

    counterLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    counterLabel.name = @"myCounterLabel";
    //counterLabel.text = @"0";
    counterLabel.fontSize = 50;
    counterLabel.fontColor = [SKColor yellowColor];
    counterLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.0f, self.size.height / 1.3f);

    [self addChild: counterLabel];

    id wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.5];
    id run = [SKAction runBlock:^ {

        counter++;
        counterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];


    }];
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[wait, run]]];
    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[wait, run]]]];
}
```

NOTE: Remove any code related to the counter label from the update method.

Comment: When I add this it doesn't work. I've edited the original post to add the `update` method. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks so much! Sorry I was getting confused with the `update` method.